# Bounded harmonic function in the unit disc centered at origin .

Tags: complex-analysis, maximum-principle

Find a bounded harmonic function in unit disc centered at origin and taking value $\sin 2\theta$ on boundary.
I tried many ways to solve this question but not getting the answer as $r^2\sin 2\theta$.
Please give the algorithm to find bounded harmonic function.

Comment: The Dirichlet problem for the ball is classically solved by separation of the variables $r$ and $\theta$

Comment: There is an integral formula for the general solution in $n$ dimensions.